# Qt Ui namespace

Tags: c++, qt

What is the significance of the namespace `Ui` that is auto-generated by Qt?

Are these two namespaces the same?

In the first one, which contains a forward declaration of the class MainWindow from `ui_MainWindow.h` why is it not declared as `class Ui::MainWindow`? How does the compiler know that MainWindow is coming from the auto-generated Ui header?

In MainWindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow; //MainWindow from ui_MainWindow.h
}
```

In ui_MainWindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui
```

Answer (score 6):

It is used to group your auto-generated windows in one name-space. It helps to differentiate between the ui class that is generated from designer ui file and the class that implements the functionality.

Comment: I know why a namespace is used in `MainWindow.h`, I guess I meant why is there a namespace Ui created in `Ui_MainWindow.h`. And how does `class MainWindow` in the namespace Ui in `MainWindow.h` know it is a forward declaration of the `MainWindow` class in the Ui file rather than the one created by me.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the significance of the namespace Ui that is auto-generated by Qt?

So that it resides in its own "bubble" and will not conflict with any other similarly named class, like the one that you create explicitly. Sure, they could have make that it is being called differently and so on, but even then namespaces are good practice in C++ to deal with to avoid clashes.

> Are these two namespaces the same?

Yes, of course, namespaces with the same name within the same parent namespace are always the same in a project.

> I guess I meant why is there a namespace Ui created in Ui_MainWindow.h.

Well, wherever else would it be created, really? There needs to be some file where this code is generated, not polluting any existing source file with generated code on the fly. Whether it happens to be called the way it is, is just personal taste again.

> And how does class MainWindow in the namespace Ui in MainWindow.h know it is a forward declaration of the MainWindow class in the Ui file rather than the one created by me.

Well, this has nothing to do with Qt, it is just C++ basics. It seems to me you do not get what namespaces are and how they are used. It will be "tagged" with the namespace, so the compiler will of course know which one it refers to. Now imagine this without namespace. It would be totally ambiguous for the compiler then.

Comment: mWhat do you mean by "tagged" with the namespace? In the .moc file? I tried creating a class and putting it into the namespace Ui in `Ui_Mainwindow.h` and couldn't add a forward declaration in `Mainwindow.h` without getting errors.

Comment: @MicroPenguin: this is basic C++ -> http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html Chapter 14.

Comment: Okay, oops. I was confused because Ui_MainWindow.h was autogenerated and hidden. I believe it's regenerated at compile time. But overall, they are the same namespace.

Comment: @MicroPenguin What do you mean by "it's hidden". *You* include it into your `mainwindow.cpp` file - it's in *your* code. Remember: the responsibility for the source files that are not regenerated at compile time is *yours*. Just because something comes from a template in Qt Creator doesn't absolve you from having to understand *exactly* what's going on. Explain it to [a rubber ducky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). If you can't, then you don't understand it - but you should.

Comment: @KubaOber: heh, RDD made me smile :-)

Comment: @FinalContest My 50 gram rubber ducky has saved my sanity more than once, and my employer many times [its weight in gold](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2850+grams%29%28price+of+gold%29).