# Defining a class in a different form than its declaration form

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, namespaces

In the code pieces below, there are //HERE tagged comments.

In this regions, you see the same namespace declarations. In the first declaration, ShapeChanging class is forward declared. And in the second part, ShapeChanging class is derived from another class. So, it is defined in a different form than its declaration form?

I did not know that language rule. Can anyone explain it?

First: Header file of my widget

```
#ifndef SHAPECHANGING_H
#define SHAPECHANGING_H

#include <QDialog>

//HERE
namespace Ui {
    class ShapeChanging;
}

class ShapeChanging : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ShapeChanging(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ShapeChanging();

private:
    Ui::ShapeChanging *ui;
};

#endif // SHAPECHANGING_H
```

Second: the file generated by uic

```
#ifndef UI_SHAPECHANGING_H
#define UI_SHAPECHANGING_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
...

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_ShapeChanging
{
public:
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_2;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
...
};

//HERE
namespace Ui {
    class ShapeChanging: public Ui_ShapeChanging {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_SHAPECHANGING_H
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use QT but my quick search indicates that QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE/QT_END_NAMESPACE depend on project configuration settings so without knowing what they expand to this is unanswerable. It may be that QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE is simply an alternate for your "namespace UI" or it may be something else entirely.

Comment: I find the answer of this confusing. It is a namespace forward declaration. It was forward declarated in the header file of my widget, and implemented in the file generated by uic.

Answer (score 0):

`QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` / `QT_END_NAMESPACE` is a macro that expands if Qt was compiled with custom namespace (which will not occur in case you downloaded it from Qt website). This option is useful if you are compiling Qt to be used with library that have name collisions with Qt - you can read more about it here: http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_In_Namespace.

For your second question, I think they just wanted to group all classes generated by UIC into single namespace (same thing is discussed here [Qt Ui namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855666/qt-ui-namespace)). I'm not sure what is the rationale with two classes, maybe there are some historical reasons or it was easier to write generator template for it this way.

Only thing I can really thing about is that since Qt is been around forever it was also targeting compilers without proper namespace support so they wanted to have `Ui` namespace as optional thing that can be easily turned off.